# Cloud shell via android?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-shell

is there anyway to access the google cloud shell on an android device?

Im trying to access the shell to use the given processing vs a vm instance. Although I am not emtirely sure it will process image recognition training any faster. Will it?

Comment: Cmon people. Where's the great and helpful community at? :/

Answer (score 2):

The cloud console app now has cloud shell support

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any ways to access cloud shell on an android device since the there are no compatible browsers and since Cloud Shell is not avaiable via ordinary ssh clients.

And no processing will not be faster since cloud shell uses the smallest instance type

`When you start Cloud Shell, it provisions an f1-micro Google Compute Engine virtual machine running a Debian-based Linux operating system. Cloud Shell instances are provisioned on a per-user, per-session basis. The instance persists while your Cloud Shell session is active and terminates after an hour of inactivity`.

From here https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features